# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, custom-error-pages

I'm making Ionic PWA in Angular. During loading application I get error message in console which is shown bellow. I think there is something with the pages, I get the same message when I open any other page as well. Also it always loads page successfully, but it takes quite a while to load it.

[image: Error]

I thought the problem is in 'app-routing.module.ts' but it looks fine. The AuthGuard works fine because it's redirecting me to the right page.

When I build it, I have got the same issue on the terminal.

```
[2022-11-02T14:10:30.741Z]  "GET /admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
[2022-11-02T14:10:30.744Z]  "GET /admin" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I didn't got any error on localhost but on localhost the browser don't find the service worker and can't use PWA.

I don't know what to copy because I don't know where to find the problem. Any suggestions?

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './guard/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'tabs',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      type: 'user',
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/admin/admin.module').then( m => m.AdminPageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      type: 'admin'
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I researched a lot but I don't find any other question with this type of issue when the page cause the error.
I added PathLocationStrategy and LocationStrategy to 'app.module.ts'

```
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

...

  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy},
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy} 
  ],
```

I use this:

```
ionic build --prod && http-server www/
```

Find below the 'admin-routing.module.ts'

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DayPilotModule } from '@daypilot/daypilot-lite-angular';

import { AdminPage } from './admin.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminPage
  },
  {
    path: 'add-photo',
    loadChildren: () => import('./add-photo/add-photo.module').then( m => m.AddPhotoPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    DayPilotModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdminPageRoutingModule {}
```

```
Versions:

Angular CLI: 13.3.3
Node: 17.8.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 13.3.4
... core

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1303.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular       13.3.9
@angular-devkit/core                13.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics          13.3.3
@angular/animations                 7.2.16
@angular/cdk                        14.2.4
@angular/cli                        13.3.3
@angular/common                     13.3.3
@angular/compiler                   13.3.3
@angular/compiler-cli               13.3.3
@angular/fire                       7.3.0
@angular/forms                      13.3.3
@angular/language-service           13.3.3
@angular/material                   14.2.4
@angular/platform-browser           13.3.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   13.3.3
@angular/router                     13.3.3
@angular/service-worker             13.3.3
@schematics/angular                 13.3.3
rxjs                                6.6.7
typescript                          4.4.4


Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.3 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.3.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.3.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.3.3
   @angular/cli                  : 13.3.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0
```

Comment: How does the routing looks like in your admin module ?

Comment: Which version of Angular & Ionic are you using?

Comment: It seems to issue with the http-server, Just for curiosity,  can you run the www folder with some extension for vscode such as live server - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer?  to make sure the www folder is built correctly?

Comment: I tried it but it's not working, I have got many other errors, most of them '404 (Not Found)'.

Comment: We can try to discuss further in SoF chat if you like, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249253/ionic

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot use the chat. 'You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.'

Comment: I Would like to help, but I guess I need to see some more stuff to help:|  If you have any other way to discuss ...

Comment: Don't use http-server, it [doesn't support single page apps](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/318) like angular. I believe [serve](https://github.com/vercel/serve) does.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still not working well.

Comment: It seems I came across a similar error: PWA + a riderection from `""` to `"xxx"` results in a 404 error for `"xxx"`. I can't see this error without the PWA functionality, so it is a culprit. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `AdminPageModule` defined (just a `AdminPageRoutingModule` which is different), at least your code samples don't show any, but You refer to it in `AppRoutingModule`. Therefore the `404`-Error.
In other words, it is not sufficient to define a route, you also need to make sure, that the Component or Module exists, the route refers to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have AdminPageModule just didn't copy it to here.

Comment: Yeah, but you definitively should show us a copy here. How can you expect to get help, if you don't show us your problem in necessary  detail? Ideally you have a public github repo or stackblitz or whatever with a running example showing the problem.